# Is it possible to show dynamic data in default Settings app from my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, settings

I am using settings bundle to insert some items in iPhone's default settings app.

now when selecting my app name  from iPhone's settings app , can we able to list data from Database of my application.

When checking some URLs, it seems that we cant show dynamic data in the settings app.

What i am trying to do is,

Settings -> MyAppName -> When tapped MyAppName

I want to fetch data from my DB and display it like below in the uitableview.also to add new entry by tapping + ( add button ) from there.

Fruits
Vegtables
Icecream
Chocolates
Mobiles

like that and when tapping on the each entry take it to the next set of list. and also there they can add new entry

Can this all be done?

Please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry, it can't be done. You'll have to have the settings inside your app and include your own view controller for the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not do this, because as a app you can write only to the documents directory of your app. So to have something displayed in the settings you have to create Settings.bundle in your main bundle. You can read from your main bundle the Settings.bundle files but you can not write to it.